# Android | TextView.setText() not work

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

So I have such quite complicated fragment. It is fragment used in [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and it's populated by own [`CursorLoader`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) and also contains some [`ListFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)s added via [`getChildFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getChildFragmentManager()).

In `onCreate()` I assign view elements and initiat Loader like so

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_account, container, false);

    mUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_account_full_name);
    mUserLastSeen = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_account_user_last_seen);
    mCreditBalance = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_account_credit_balance);
    ...

    // then I populate FrameLayouts with ListViewFragments
    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.user_account_credit_history, CreditListFragment.newInstance(mUserId));
    ft.add(R.id.user_account_bill_consumption, ConsumptionListFragmentAccount.newInstance(mUserId));
    ft.commit();

    // initiating the Loader
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    return v;
}
```

and finally in `onLoadFinished()` I want populate my view

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    data.moveToFirst();
    Log.e("TAG", data.getString(UserId.NAME));
    mUserName.setText(data.getString(UserId.NAME));
    mUserLastSeen.setText(getString(R.string.last_seen) + ": " +
            (data.isNull(UserId.LAST_VISIT) ? getString(R.string.never) :
                    String.format("%te. %<tB %<tY", data.getLong(UserId.LAST_VISIT))));
    Utils.setColorCurrency(mCreditBalance, data.getFloat(UserId.ACCOUNT_BALANCE));
}
```

but the `View` is not populated. The `Log.e(...)` writes user name as expected, so the `Loader` is initiated ad has valid data, but none of my `TextView`s is replaced with the data, which is very, very strange.

Any ideas?

---

**EDIT**/ Got it!

Solution moved to answer. Thanks all, especially to Shoeb Siddique, for your help! You are a star!

Comment: Show you XML and LogCat.

Comment: Is `onLoadFinished` called on the main thread? If not, that's probably the culprit here.

Comment: Dont know in which thread is `onLoadFinished()` called, its member method of my `Fragment` and I used it that way many times and never had a trouble.

Comment: first your logcat dose not print username. Second `onLoadFinished` is called on main thread. Third calling `getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);` at `onResume` destroys the great idea behind the loader framework.

Comment: @MML13 First, it prints. Second and third, what's a problem and can I solve it?

Comment: Why are you making view final??

Comment: @VivekMishra no purpose behind it. Making it non final does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `ViewPager` there were numerous sibling `Fragment`s and I used the same `loaderId = 0` in all of them.

If loader with the same `Context`, `loaderId` and `LoaderCallbacks` exists, [`LoaderManager.initLoader()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) returns the already created loader, so all my Fragments shared one `Loader`.

The `Fragment`, that initiated the `Loader` firs, lets call it `clickFragment`, was not populated by the `LoaderCallbacks` and so was all Fragments left from the `clickFragment`, while all Fragments right/next to `clickFragment` were populated with data of `clickFragment`. So the `clickFragment` initiated the `Loader` and as the `ViewPager` prepared the sibling Fragments, the data were delivered to all right Fragments. Strangely, the `clickFragment` itself was not populated and I did not slide the view to siblings, so I saw just empty `View` and was confused.

Now I generate unique `loaderId` for each fragment and it finally works.

Answer (score 2):

```
  mUserName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_account_full_name);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { 

                 mUserName.setText(data.getString(UserId.NAME));
        mUserLastSeen.setText(getString(R.string.last_seen) + ": " +
                (data.isNull(UserId.LAST_VISIT) ? getString(R.string.never) :
                        String.format("%te. %<tB %<tY", data.getLong(UserId.LAST_VISIT))));
        Utils.setColorCurrency(mCreditBalance, data.getFloat(UserId.ACCOUNT_BALANCE));
                } 
            });
```

Comment: Nope, that did not helped.

Comment: Are you getting data? data.getString(UserId.NAME)?

Comment: Yes, I get valid data, it prints `Log.e(...)` in `runOnUiThread()` as well as `onLoadFinished` thread.

Comment: So may be the problem in your style. Can you please show you style.

Comment: I don't think problem is there, if I call `setText()` in `onCreateView()`, the `textView()` *is* populated, but not from `onLoadFinished()`.

Comment: Please try handler to set text in onLoadFinished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99089/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-vaclav).

Answer (score 1):

You can use User Interface thread ***runOnUiThread***:

```
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    data.moveToFirst();
    Log.e("TAG", data.getString(UserId.NAME));
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mUserName.setText(data.getString(UserId.NAME));
            mUserLastSeen.setText(getString(R.string.last_seen) + ": " +
                    (data.isNull(UserId.LAST_VISIT) ? getString(R.string.never) :
                            String.format("%te. %<tB %<tY", data.getLong(UserId.LAST_VISIT))));
        }
    });

    Utils.setColorCurrency(mCreditBalance, data.getFloat(UserId.ACCOUNT_BALANCE));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this not fix my issue.